# How to dump memory into raw file in Ollydbg?

Tags: dump, ollydbg

I am debugging a process and want to dump a chunk of memory, say from memory address `0x4160d8` to `0x4200d8`, into a file.

How can I get a raw file that includes just the bytes? I tried to use the OllyDump plugin but it creates an executable file with PE headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dump memory into a raw file using Olly by following these steps:

1. select the memory area you want to dump
2. right-click and select "Open in a separate dump window"
3. right-click the dump in the new window and select "Backup > Save data to file..."